# React Native Component not Scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was creating an app that required a scrollable page, I used a header component with a linear gradient background which was as per the design given to me, I noticed that after adding this component the View was not scrolling entirely, the more the height of the background component the less my component can scroll,

Here is my code

`Main Component File`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from '../../axios.config';
import {ScrollView, View, Text, Image, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';

import Button from '../../components/Button';
import OutlineButton from '../../components/OutlineButton';
import Rating from '../../components/Rating';
import Header from './components/Header';
import BookDataRail from './components/BookDataRail';

import {Book} from '../../types/Book';
import {ReadBook, PlayWhite} from '../../icons';
import styles from './styles';
import Review from '../../components/Review';

interface BookDetailsProps {}

const BookDetails: React.FC<BookDetailsProps> = () => {
  const [bookDetails, setBookDetails] = useState<Book>();
  const {width} = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.post('/', {
        method: 'bookdetails',
        book_id: 4,
      });

      setBookDetails(data);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {/* Cover Image/Header */}
      <Header coverUrl={bookDetails?.cover_url} />
      {/* Content */}
      <View style={styles.body}>
        {/* Book Title */}
        <Text style={styles.bookTitleText}>{bookDetails?.title}</Text>
        {/* Author Name */}
        <Text style={styles.authorNameText}>{bookDetails?.author_name}</Text>
        {/* Main Rating */}
        <View style={styles.ratingContainer}>
          <Rating rating={bookDetails ? bookDetails.rating_review.rating : 0} />
        </View>
        {/* Play Audio/Read Book Buttons */}
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <Button
            title="Play Audio"
            width={'48%'}
            leftAccessory={
              <Image source={PlayWhite} style={styles.buttonIcon} />
            }
          />
          <OutlineButton
            title="Read Book"
            width={'48%'}
            leftAccessory={
              <Image source={ReadBook} style={styles.buttonIcon} />
            }
          />
        </View>
        {/* Add to Wishlist */}
        <Text style={styles.addToWishlistText}>+ Add to Wishlist</Text>
        {/* Book Details Rail */}
        <View style={styles.bookRailContainer}>
          {bookDetails && (
            <BookDataRail
              downloads={bookDetails.downloads}
              language={bookDetails.language}
              pages={bookDetails.num_pages}
              genre={bookDetails.genre_name}
            />
          )}
        </View>
        {/* Book Description */}
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Summary</Text>
          <ScrollView
            nestedScrollEnabled
            style={styles.descriptionTextContainer}>
            <RenderHtml
              contentWidth={width}
              source={{html: bookDetails?.description || ''}}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        {/* Ratings */}
        <View style={styles.ratingsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Reviews</Text>
          {/* Ratings Header */}
          <View style={styles.ratingsHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.ratingText}>
              {bookDetails?.rating.toFixed(1)}
            </Text>
            <View>
              <View style={styles.ratingContainerSmall}>
                <Rating
                  rating={bookDetails ? bookDetails.rating_review.rating : 0}
                  noText
                />
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.numRatingsText}>
                {bookDetails?.rating_review.review_comments.length || 0} reviews
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          {/* Showing all reviews */}
          <View style={styles.reviewCommentsContainer}>
            {bookDetails?.rating_review.review_comments.map(
              (reviewComment, index) => (
                <Review
                  key={index}
                  name={reviewComment.name}
                  rating={reviewComment.rating}
                  date={reviewComment.date}
                  comment={reviewComment.comment}
                />
              ),
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default BookDetails;
```

`Header File (Linear Gradient component is rendered here)`

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image} from 'react-native';
import BackButton from '../../../../components/BackButton';
import {hasNotch} from 'react-native-device-info';

import {HorizontalThreeDots} from '../../../../icons';
import HeaderLinearGradient from '../../../../components/HeaderLinearGradient';
import styles from './styles';

interface HeaderProps {
  coverUrl: string | undefined;
}

const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({coverUrl}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderLinearGradient height={hasNotch() ? '22%' : '22%'} />
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.headerOptionsContainer}>
          <BackButton color="white" />
          <Image
            source={HorizontalThreeDots}
            style={styles.headerOptionImage}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.coverImageContainer}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: coverUrl,
            }}
            style={styles.coverImage}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

`Linear Gradient File`

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {StyleProp, ViewStyle} from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

interface HeaderLinearGradientProps {
  height?: number | string;
  styles?: StyleProp<ViewStyle> | any;
}

const HeaderLinearGradient: React.FC<HeaderLinearGradientProps> = ({
  height,
  children,
  styles,
}) => {
  const colors = useRef(['#4685EC', '#00296B']);

  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={colors.current}
      style={{
        ...styles,
        minHeight: height || '30%',
      }}>
      {children}
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};

export default HeaderLinearGradient;
```

I have tried multiple solutions, but the one that kinda worked was setting the height of the main component file as something like `140%`, but I cannot use this as a lot of the content on this page is dynamic,

Here is a demo of the issue I'm facing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/121x2CNuj3M63aJu_Z1PjxYbYxivCrhuP/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding `height: Dimensions.get('screen').height` to container